# NoClassDefFoundError: related to packaging of files for Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have this web service:

```
    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "executeCleanAndValidateExtractedDate")
    public boolean executeCleanAndValidateExtractedDate()
    {
        try
        {
            CleanAndValidateExtractedData cav = new CleanAndValidateExtractedData();
            Transformation transformation = new DefaultTransformation();
            Step s1 = transformation.addStep(cav);          
            return transformation.execute();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ExecuteKeymark.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ExecuteKeymark.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I try to execute it, I get an exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5193)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5091)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/medallion/etl/impl/AbstractStepSupport
```

I am confused to why it can find that class. It was available at run time, but is no longer available. Is there something special that I need to do to deploy this so it has access to the class in Glassfish?

EDIT: Attached POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.dv</groupId>
<artifactId>WS_3</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>WS_3</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.medallion</groupId>
        <artifactId>keymark.filemonitorEJB</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-ALPHA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.medallion</groupId>
        <artifactId>etl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-ALPHA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bundle the required jar files in the war/ear file, so they are available at runtime, not just at compile time.

Comment: I am using Netbeans and MAven to manage the project. Any idea how I cam accomplish this using those?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ejb, but what I found indicates that a jar is produced at the end, so you cannot bundle your required medallion dependencies (a jar cannot contain another, AFAIK).  Do you need to produce an ejb, or would a war/ear work for you?  If yes, you could set up maven to produce that (instead of th ejb), which would include the required dependencies.  If not, you need to ensure the medallion jars are deployed in the web server's common libs directory